# How does this function sum 3 integers using only bit-wise operators?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
int sum3(int x, int y, int z) {

  /* use XOR to combine x, y, and z, use word2 to store carry bit. */

  int word1 = 0;
  int word2 = 0;

  word1 = (x^y) ^ z;
  word2 = ( (x&y) | (x&z) | (y&z) ) << 1;

  return sum(word1,word2);
}
```

I don't understand the "why" behind it. I understand it has something to do with carry bits

EDIT:
Here's sum:

```
static int sum(int x, int y) {
  return x+y;
}
```

So I lied, it does use + in the end

Comment: This isn't even a complete example.

Comment: @user3114056 - Please show `sum(word1,word2)`.

Comment: From a cursory glance, it looks like a [carry lookahead adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder)?

Comment: "So I lied, it does use + in the end" So what's your question now? Do you have a question now?

Comment: @starrify yes, what is happening before that?

Comment: @user3114056 If that's your question now, please edit the question body to make it clear.

Comment: looks more like it's generating a hash value for the 3 numbers rather than adding them up... probably a mis-named function.

Comment: No, it **is** adding them.  Look up the function of half- and full- adders.  This is just doing that on a word worth of bits.  Though rather uselessly as the ALU almost certainly contains an ordinary "add" pathway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we have to add  any number of integers, the sum can be calculated by doing a bi wise XOR operation.
So consider we have  A = 0x10 = (0001 0000)bin
                and  B = 0x11 = (0001 0001)bin
To add these numbers we can do bit wise XOR operation so when the numbers are different it gives 1 and else gives 0.

So A XOR B = 0010 0001 this gives the sum.

In case if you have a carry, you have to add that after shifting one position and that is what sum(int int) does.

Comment: A XOR B = 0000 00001 in your example

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, word2 is all the carry bits right?

Answer (score 2):

xor is logically "add without carry"

Imagine you have a 1 bit computer.

```
0+0 = 0
0+1 = 1
1+0 = 1
```

All good so far right?

Then

```
1+1 = 0
```

Here, we know the answer is 2d or 10b, but on a 1 bit machine the 2s bit is lost to overflow.

That truth table is exactly what you get with the XOR operation.

```
0^0 = 0
0^1 = 1
1^0 = 1
1^1 = 0
```

So how do you tell where a carry occurs?  Those can only happen when the bit positions are equal, which is tested via AND.  So in the above only 1+1 leads to a carry.  And a carry means adding 1 bit in a leftshifted position, so A&B << 1 gives the new carry.

You can extend this from 1 bit to any number of bits and see the basic logic works out.  It's slightly more complicated in that you may have to ripple the carry throughout the operation but we will ignore that for now (as your example does).

Now we can look at adding a 3rd number.  Checking the logic you can see the fundamentals still work here too.

```
1+1+1 = 3d = 11b = 1b if we throw out the overflow
1^1^1 = 1b
```

Overflow can only occur once at each bit position so checking all combinations to see if overflow occurs (via AND), and then ORing them together gets all the carries.

The logic you have won't extend to 4 values though, because it can't handle multiple carries at a single position (because it ORs them together it can only represent 1 carry at any position).

Your algorithm doesn't handle ripple really, that's covered at the end by calling the normal adder which is just the '+' operation.  A fully functional example would have to behave differently, perhaps by operating on 1 bit at a time.